# Activity recreation due to Theme.Translucent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I have an application with one parent and some child activities. Requirement is to play some custom animation on child activity launch. For smooth animation and avoid delay between switching I applied Theme.Translucent on application in the Manifest. Animation is running properly and application behavior is proper until I turn developer setting ON to keep single activity.

Application stuck at the parent activity due to infinite recreation (onCreate() followed by onStart(), onResume(), onDestroy and so on) when there.
1) Developer setting is ON to keep single activity.
2) My application goes in the background with child activity is on the top.
3) My activity comes to the foreground.

I am facing this issue only on Android 4.0 series but found in the documentation that Theme Translucent is for API Level 10 and below.

I think activity recreation issue is due to translucency of child activity that is on the top and parent is below. As child activity is translucent, its require parent activity in the background. App creating parent in background and its being destroyed due to developer setting is ON.

I tried to find Translucent equal for API level above 10 but no luck. Is there any API to Translucent activities with API level above 10 or any other way to avoid flickering/delay between activity switching.

Thanks

Comment: So what approach have you chosen towards theme.Translucent? (in your xml or java code)

Comment: I have added theme Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar into the manifest file for the particular activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your activity to have a translucent window, you can add:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

To your `AppTheme` in `res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: android:windowIsTranslucent is creating the problem. Making it true showing perfect animation and recreation issue. Making it false not showing proper animation but application running perfect.